# Not able to access on demand resource in other file using swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, on-demand-resources

I started to work on **on demand resource**. I'm able to download the resource but i'm not able to use those resources in other files. please some one help me in fixing this issue. `PFA` code.

```
 public class RBPExtensions: NSObject {
    class func prefechDataForTag(_ tagArray: [String], completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {

            if let tags = NSSet(array: tagArray) as? Set<String> {

               let resourceRequest = NSBundleResourceRequest.init(tags: tags, bundle: Bundle.main)

                resourceRequest.conditionallyBeginAccessingResources { (resourceFound) in
                    if resourceFound {

                        completion(true)
                    } else {

resourceRequest.beginAccessingResources(completionHandler: { (error) in

                            if error != nil {

                                completion(false)
                            } else {

                                let image = UIImage(named: "filter_button_filled")

                                completion(true)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            } else {

                completion(false)
            }

        }
    }
```

---

calling this method as :

```
 RBPExtensions.prefechDataForTag(["Image"], completion: { (success) in

            })
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by "in other file".

Comment: i declared this function in one separate class A and i need downloaded resource in class B

Comment: Hi how to use on demand resource for images in images.xcassets